# Order of compilation in an AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a template in an Angular app with two main components/directives. One of them is a selector and the other one is a slider. Basically I need to use the first one to show up the results in the slider. For some reason, the slider is compiled before the selector even though is defined after in the HTML (Jade in this case):

```
-
  var att = [
    {
      source: ".competitors",
      property: ".competitor",
      klass: "green"
    }
  ];
  att = JSON.stringify(att);

p.prompt Some text.

xplr-selector-list-limit.flexbox(xplr-id="attributes" property="selected")

xplr-slider(xplr-id="attributes" ticks="10" range="[1,10]" low-label='Low'       high-label='High' xplr-join="#{att}" xplr-select="selected" property="selected" type="competitor")
```

Then, my question is: **is there any way to tell an AngularJS directive to be compiled and run before another one?** Just to add that directives don't share any controller and they are not parent-child, there is just a service using the selector data to initialize the slider (this works after the slider is already compiled, created and showed up in my template, and this is not what needed). Thanks for your reading/answering in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically : if they are siblings elements, they will be compiled in dom order, the exception beeing that directive with "template" are compiled synchronously, where directives using templateUrl are always compiled asynchronously, causing random effective compilation order between them.

Now more in concept : Siblings directives should never depends on each other directly, you should never initialize data for sibling B from sibling A, even by setting the data in a service.. This would be the responsability of a parent directive or controller, wrapping both sibling A & sibling B.

Comment: That is correct, I'm using templateUrl so that can be the reason why there is this random compilation. Your second argument made me think about how I'm implementing this functionality. Basically what you mean is that both slider and selector components should share a parent controller or directive, right? In that case, is it possible to define another directive from scratch and then turn it into the parent of the two siblings?